# Django - how do I override default date formats per locale?

Tags: python, django

We are using Django 1.11 for [Speedy Net](https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net). I want to override the default values of `DATE_FORMAT` and `MONTH_DAY_FORMAT` in English, but keep the default values (or define them again) in Hebrew. So they will not be the same and will not be identical to Django's default values. In English we will have:

```
DATE_FORMAT = 'j F Y'
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT = 'j F'
YEAR_FORMAT = 'Y'
```

And in Hebrew:

```
DATE_FORMAT = 'j בF Y'
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT = 'j בF'
```

(and `YEAR_FORMAT` will be the same).

The template currently looks like this:

```
{% if can_view_profile and user.date_of_birth %}
    {% if can_view_dob_day_month or can_view_dob_year %}
        <tr>
            <th>{% if can_view_dob_day_month %}{% trans 'Birth Date' %}{% elif can_view_dob_year %}{% trans 'Birth Year' %}{% endif %}</th>
            <td>
                {% if can_view_dob_day_month and can_view_dob_year %}
                    {{ user.date_of_birth|date:settings.DATE_FORMAT }}
                {% elif can_view_dob_day_month %}
                    {{ user.date_of_birth|date:settings.MONTH_DAY_FORMAT }}
                {% elif can_view_dob_year %}
                    {{ user.date_of_birth|date:settings.YEAR_FORMAT }}
                {% endif %}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

And I want it to display the dates in these formats in each language. How do I do it?

**Update:** I found out that it's possible to override formats per locale in [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/formatting/), and added formats for `en` and `he` locales, but they don't work. I added a debugging code which you can see [here](https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/blob/uri_main_branch_2019-07-26_c/speedy/core/locale/en/formats.py#L4), but it doesn't work. It shows dates like `Jan. 1, 2018` and not as I expect.

I also don't know if `DATE_FORMAT` should be preceded by `settings.` in the template, but it doesn't show anything without it.

I also want to keep a default setting if one of these formats is not defined in a specific locale, or for locales which I didn't define at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Defining default date formats

> I also want to keep a default setting if one of these formats is not defined in a specific locale, or for locales which I didn't define at all.

> As far as I'm aware you can only choose one of `DATE_FORMAT`, `DATETIME_FORMAT`, `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT` or `SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT` - I don't think it's possible to specify your own unless you hard-code the actual format (which then would not change with locale). – [solarissmoke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3955830/solarissmoke)

You can patch `django.utils.formats.FORMAT_SETTINGS` so that it will look in your Django settings:

```py
from django.conf import settings as django_settings
from django.utils import formats

formats.FORMAT_SETTINGS = formats.FORMAT_SETTINGS.union(django_settings.FORMAT_SETTINGS)
```

In your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` (or, in the case of Speedy Net, **speedy/core/settings/base.py**):

```py
YEAR_FORMAT = 'Y'

FORMAT_SETTINGS = (
    'YEAR_FORMAT',
)
```

## About patching

It only needs to be run once to be applied to all of the views (templates), so I would put it in **speedy/core/patches/locale_patches.py** `def patch` and call `locale_patches.patch()` <s>in **wsgi.py**</s>.

> But the problem is I had to patch 14 files because the tests failed and I had to patch the tests too. You can see my commit https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/commit/f5dc4896c136a816ab9fe0dc360d3fd59d0a5f33. Isn't it possible to apply this without patching so many files?

I found another way: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#configuring-applications

Subclass `AppConfig` in **speedy/core/apps.py**:

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig

from .patches import locale_patches


class SpeedyCoreConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'speedy.core'

    def ready(self):
        locale_patches.patch()
```

Put the dotted path to that subclass in `INSTALLED_APPS` in **speedy/core/settings/base.py**:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...

    'speedy.core.apps.SpeedyCoreConfig',  # Add this line
    'speedy.core.base',
    ...
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I decided to add `def ready` in the config of `speedy.core.base` and not to add another new app. I also used `default_app_config` although I understand this is discouraged by the Django developers. You can see my commit on https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/commit/c1549acf17fa3d1742563e2c2248682ff43fb502. I'm accepting this answer.

Answer (score 5):

The way you're overriding the locale looks fine. The issue is with how you're specifying the format in your template:

```
{{ user.date_of_birth|date:settings.DATE_FORMAT }}
```

I'm not sure where `settings` is coming from, but in any case that will not work - it will use the format defined in your main settings file (if that is what is being passed to the template context), and this will not be localised. You need instead to pass a string that describes which format you want to use

```
{{ user.date_of_birth|date:"DATE_FORMAT" }}
```

This will cause the `date` filter to go an look for the appropriate format in the current locale, and apply that. The fact that you need to pass a string here is alluded to by example in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#date), but it isn't made explicit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works. I was not aware that Django expects a string. But how do I define a default setting if they are not defined in a specific locale? For example for `YEAR_FORMAT` or any other format.

Comment: What you define is `settings.py` should become the default and you can override the one in `formats.py`

Comment: @TarunLalwani This is not true on my Django 1.11. What I define in settings is not used as the default.

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can only choose one of `DATE_FORMAT`, `DATETIME_FORMAT`, `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT` or `SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT` - I don't think it's possible to specify your own unless you hard-code the actual format (which then would not change with locale). If you need more flexibility you could write your own template tag to do this.

Comment: @solarissmoke OK, I'm accepting this answer as the accepted answer with bounty, although it doesn't address my question about default.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at your project and there few concerns

- You have used `locale` folder to override the locale setting instead of formats. This is not right, you should just use formats
- Now formats don't allow sharing between languages, so you can't have a default values

So if you want all settings to come from your settings module, then you need use them in the `formats.py`

**speedy/core/locales/he/formats.py**

```py
from django.utils import formats
from django.conf import settings

local_variables = locals()
for format in formats.FORMAT_SETTINGS:
    if hasattr(settings, format):
        local_variables[format] = getattr(settings, format)

DATE_FORMAT = 'j בF Y'
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT = 'j בF'
YEAR_FORMAT = 'Y'


DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    '%Y-%m-%d',                           # '2006-10-25',
]
```

This way, you first use all format defined in settings and then override anything language specific

Comment: I tried to use the same structure used in Django, for example you can see here - https://github.com/django/django/tree/stable/1.11.x/django/conf/locale/he. The `formats.py` file in https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/conf/locale/he/formats.py doesn't use code as you suggested but it still uses defaults. How can I use defaults in a similar way?

Comment: Speedy Net uses similar `formats.py` files, for example on https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/blob/staging/speedy/core/locale/en/formats.py

Comment: Yes, but that will still take values from default locales defined in `django.conf.locale` in case its not found in your locale

Comment: See this https://github.com/django/django/blob/3deda1f680ef34a753f6d872813737f363cb4886/django/utils/formats.py#L78

Comment: You can see that `FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK`, for example, is not defined on https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/conf/locale/he/formats.py and it's value comes from a default value (if I'm correct, https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/conf/global_settings.py). I want to extend these settings with my own default formats. How do I do it?

Comment: One way or the other you need to define them, either individually in every localization file or the way I have added in the answer, if you define them individually then they not more of a default as such

Comment: The defaults should include a locale which I didn't define at all. For example if I'm using the `de` locale, then it needs to take `YEAR_FORMAT` from my default settings and the other formats from the Django locale formats, or from my default settings if I define them there.